# bash grep log file for string then mailx

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

I'm looking to modify a script to search the log files produced by the script, grep for a string, then mailx if the string is found.

From the below script I want to only send the logs where rows are returned rather than all logs.  35+ databases daily is a log.

pseudo code:

```
if grep TOTAL $REPORTS/${ORACLE_SID}_Tablespace.log
then 
mail -s "$ORACLE_SID Tablespace Alert" `cat $ORAMAIL/dba_list` < \
$REPORTS/${ORACLE_SID}_Tablespace.log
fi

begin script:

. /u01/app/oracle/oraconfig/Oracle.env.new.vars

echo "$0 execution started "`date`

for NAME in `cat $ORACONFIG/dbname.list`
do
ORACLE_SID=$NAME
export ORACLE_SID

sqlplus  '/ as sysdba' <<EOF > $REPORTS/${ORACLE_SID}_Tablespace.log 2>&1
@$TOOLS/chk_tablespace.sql
EOF

TODAY=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

mail -s "$ORACLE_SID Tablespace Alert" `cat $ORAMAIL/dba_list` < \
$REPORTS/${ORACLE_SID}_Tablespace.log


done

echo "$0 execution completed "`date`
```

Comment: You appear to be new to SO. Once you have tested the answers, if you believe  an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this easily, but I think it does what you are asking.  You can use the `if` statement, but the `&&` and short-circuiting feature of bash serves well here; it plays off the return code from grep and executes the statement after the `&&` only if the grep succeeds.  I changed your one-line HERE file into an echo statement and DRYed up your code with a variable for the log file.

```
. /u01/app/oracle/oraconfig/Oracle.env.new.vars

echo "$0 execution started "`date`

for NAME in `cat $ORACONFIG/dbname.list`
do
  export ORACLE_SID=$NAME
  logfile=$REPORTS/${ORACLE_SID}_Tablespace.log

  echo "@$TOOLS/chk_tablespace.sql" |
    sqlplus  '/ as sysdba' > $logfile 2>&1

  TODAY=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

  grep TOTAL $logfile &&
    mail -s "$ORACLE_SID Tablespace Alert" `cat $ORAMAIL/dba_list` < $logfile
done

echo "$0 execution completed "`date`
```

Comment: Never do this: `for x in $(command)` or `\`command\`` or `$var`. for-in is used for iterating arguments, not (output) strings. Instead, use a glob (eg. `*.txt`), arrays (eg. `"${names[@]}"`) or a while-read 
                loop (eg. `while read -r line`). See [Bash Pitfalls 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1) and [Don't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: You make a good point, but "never" is a strong word for this. Without any information about what is in that file, it seems reasonable to assume that the dbname.list does not contain names with spaces or meta-characters and it makes the example clearer not to try coding around an issue that may or may not be present.

Comment: I respect the way you prefer to write your answers, as long as I can comment about bad practices I find dangerous. Generally, I recommend incorporating best practices when writing any good example or a solution for a specific problem, so that one could learn how to  *understand a concept*, not just attack a specific problem, to which a "Just OK" solution works. Aside: Converting a `for line in $(cat file_name)` is fairly easy. Just `while read -r line; do ...;done < file_name`. Which is the correct and *safe* way to read a file line by line. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: The dbname.list is just a list of Oracle SIDs, like orcl1, orcl2, orcl3 on separate lines, no spaces or special characters.  Thanks for all your input, I will test shortly.